# Replacement for deprecated register keyword C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have read ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), for example) that the `register` keyword is deprecated in C++ 11.  As such, is there an equivalent to this storage-class specifier in the newer versions of the standard, or is it taken care by the compiler?

Comment: It's completely unnecessary, not unlike `inline`.

Comment: @H2CO3: `inline` is still necessary for many compilers, which can only optimise a single translation unit at a time.

Comment: deprecated doesn't mean it got removed. For the time being, you can still use it (but it won't have any effect).

Comment: @MikeSeymour What's the correlation between `inline` and the ability to optimize multiple TUs at once?

Comment: @H2CO3: `inline` allows definitions in multiple TUs, so that the function is available for inlining wherever it's called. Without it, there can only be a definition in a single TU, and some compilers won't be able to inline calls to it from other TUs.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Oh sure. I don't see how I could miss that (I have had this very problem recently.)

Comment: @H2CO3:  `inline` is **not** unnecessary.  It's just misunderstood.

Comment: Some good reading: http://www.drdobbs.com/keywords-that-arent-or-comments-by-anoth/184403859

Comment: @JohnDibling I realize...

Comment: @Hariprasad See also Herb Sutter's article [Keywords that aren't](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403859)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

We can find the rationale for deprecating *register* in [defect report 809: Deprecation of the register keyword](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4193.html#809)  which says (*emphasis mine*):

> The register keyword serves very little function, **offering no more
>   than a hint that a note says is typically ignored**. It should be
>   deprecated in this version of the standard, freeing the reserved name
>   up for use in a future standard, much like auto has been re-used this
>   time around for being similarly useless.

The [removal of register](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4340) for C++17 was [approved in the Lenexa meeting](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-lenexa-may-2015/) but it is still reserved for future use.

> The register keyword was deprecated in the 2011 C++ standard, **as its
>   effect was already implicit in the language**. It remains reserved for
>   future use by the standard, and is time to remove its vestigial
>   specification.

Because of the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) the compiler only has to emulate the *observable behavior* of the program and therefore the optimizer can via the *as-if rule* choose to keep a variable in a register if it won't effect observable behavior and presumably will in most cases make better choices since it usually has more information.

For reference also see [role of "register" C keyword?](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-05/msg00098.html) from the `gcc` mailing list, one of the [replies](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-05/msg00113.html)  in the thread says:

> I don't think the "register" keyword ever affected register allocation
>   in gcc.  For that you have to go back to compilers of the 1970s.
>
> The register keyword does still have a use, though, in a gcc
>   extension: gcc uses it in combination with asm to implement register
>   variables.

Comment: The register keyword still has some uses; see, for example, [Work around lack of Yz machine constraint under Clang?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43544072/608639)

Comment: so @shafik should I removed the register keyword from my current c++ code?

Comment: @MonaJalal Yes, or otherwise your code will stop working with new compilers.

Answer (score 18):

It was never a guarantee that the compiler would listen to you if you used the keyword (and in some cases, it was a guarantee it would ignore you, like if you took the address).

This hinting ability is now deprecated, and there is no replacement (that is standard. inline asm is not standard, but could be used).

Comment: "would ignore you, like if you took the address" Wow! My C book said the compiler must error in that case.

Comment: @Joshua "In C, the address of a register variable cannot be taken, but in C++, a variable declared register is semantically indistinguishable from a variable declared without any storage class specifiers" (from the notes section here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration ). So, your C book is correct for for C, but not for C++.

Answer (score 16):

The assumption is the compiler can assign variables to registers better than the programmer, so `register` has been deprecated and there is no other equivalent keyword in the new standard.

Comment: Hmmm.  Even though a compiler can't profile code execution, and hand-optimize.

Comment: @CodeLurker Then what's this "profile-guided optimization" (PGO) that I keep hearing about?

Comment: Oh right.  Still, I'm not willing to grant that assumption.