# Register storage specifier in C++

Tags: c++, cpu-registers

I am curious to know to behavior of `register` storage specifier in `C/C++`. Following program valid in `C++`, but in case of `C` it's not valid.

```
int main()
{
        register int i;
        int* b = &i; // Valid in C++ but not in C
}
```

So, My question I, **Why C++ allowed address operator(&) to a register variable?**

P.S : I know **register** storage specifier is deprecated in modern compiler.

Comment: It is *suggesting* the compiler to place the variable to the register, as the programmer is expecting faster access to this variable. But it doesn't *force* it.

Comment: Any reason you added the C tag for a C++ question? They are different languages!

Comment: This is a really boring answer, but "because the C++ standard says so".  It says that the `register` keyword is a "hint to the implementation that the variable so declared will be heavily used," and "in most implementations will be ignored if the address of the variable is taken."

Comment: @Olaf OP actually asks why that make a difference. Well, these are different languages, that's why.

Comment: @Olaf I was replying to a now deleted comment, with OPs statement because it answered the comment in question. I don't know what you're replying to though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Nice you still talk to me ;-) Well, still he asks about C++, thus the C tag is wrong. Just mentioning another language does not make the tag valid.

Comment: @Olaf Of course I still like talking to you. I was just a bit hindered the last month doing so ;-)

Comment: Note [register was removed in C++ recently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20618008/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: "deprecated" does not mean "removed". And I'm not sure if C++17 has already been released. See the answer by Potatoswatter.

Comment: @Olaf err will be removed in 17

Answer (score 4):

Your answer can be found here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

> In C, the address of a register variable cannot be taken, but in C++,
>   a variable declared register is semantically indistinguishable from a
>   variable declared without any storage class specifiers.

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ diverged before the C language was standardized. Both adopted the `register` keyword but only C added the restriction on the `&` operator.

Digging into the history, the C++98 standard says,

> A `register` specifier has the same semantics as an `auto` specifier together with a hint to the implementation that the object so declared will be heavily used. [*Note:* the hint can be ignored and in most implementations it will be ignored if the address of the object is taken. —*end note*]

Subsequently it was deprecated, which is an opposite direction from strengthening it with semantic restrictions. It is scheduled for removal in the upcoming C++17 standard.

(`auto` was later repurposed in C++11. Its old meaning was the same as the default storage of a local variable.)

Comment: Note: C++98 is not standard C++. This would be C++14. Better to cite the valid standard, even it it says the same.

Comment: @Olaf Old standards are still standard and valid, just old. I went for the old one because this is a question of history.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Actually the newest standard overrides all other standards.  Since the question is tagged with just C++ (no version) it should quote the standard at time of writing.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Older **versions** of standard are canceled explicitly with the release of the new version. So no, they are **not** valid standard. I'd recomment to read the foreword of the standards. For C: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp6 , for C++ you certainly will find the standard.

Comment: @Olaf I don't find similar verbiage in C++, and I don't see the relevance. Questions of language evolution should be answered by looking at evolution. I've edited a bit to emphasize why the older standard was chosen.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You seem to be right about the phrasing. However, as I read it in a draft from 2012, it follows from the wording. Anyway, I did not dig deep into the C++ documents and don't intend to for this subject. Still it would be good if you use the current version or clarify any differences, which you did - thanks for the edit, it is indeed very informative and shows that C++ is quite evolving in contrast to C since C99.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is explained by this quote from the C++ Standard (7.1.1 Storage class speciﬁers)

> 3 A register speciﬁer is a hint to the implementation that the
>   variable so declared will be heavily used. [Note: The hint can be
>   ignored and **in most implementations it will be ignored if the
>   address of the variable is taken**. This use is deprecated (see D.2).
>   —end note]

Answer (score 2):

> So, My question I, **Why C++ allowed address operator(&) to a register variable?**

The answer is:
Because C and C++ are different languages and follow different standards as pointed out in the other answers.