# Work around lack of Yz machine constraint under Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, sse, inline-assembly, sha

We use inline assembly to make SHA instructions available if `__SHA__` is not defined. Under GCC we use:

```
GCC_INLINE __m128i GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB
MM_SHA256RNDS2_EPU32(__m128i a, const __m128i b, const __m128i c)
{
    asm ("sha256rnds2 %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(a) : "xm"(b), "Yz" (c));
    return a;
}
```

Clang does not consume GCC's [`Yz` constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) (see [Clang 3.2 Issue 13199](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13199) and [Clang 3.9 Issue 32727](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32727)), which is required by the `sha256rnds2` instruction:

> ```
> Yz
>
>     First SSE register (%xmm0).
> ```

We added a `mov` for Clang:

```
asm ("mov %2, %%xmm0; sha256rnds2 %%xmm0, %1, %0" : "+x"(a) : "xm"(b), "x" (c) : "xmm0");
```

Performance is off by about 3 cycles per byte. On my 2.2 GHz Celeron J3455 test machine (Goldmont with SHA extensions), that's about 230 MiB/s. Its non-trivial.

Looking at the disassembly, Clang is not optimizing around SHA's `k` when two rounds are performed:

```
Breakpoint 2, SHA256_SSE_SHA_HashBlocks (state=0xaaa3a0,
    data=0xaaa340, length=0x40) at sha.cpp:1101
1101        STATE1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) &state[4]);
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function SHA256_SSE_SHA_HashBlocks(unsigned int*, unsigned int const*, unsigned long):
   0x000000000068cdd0 <+0>:     sub    $0x308,%rsp
   0x000000000068cdd7 <+7>:     movdqu (%rdi),%xmm0
   0x000000000068cddb <+11>:    movdqu 0x10(%rdi),%xmm1
   ...
   0x000000000068ce49 <+121>:   movq   %xmm2,%xmm0
   0x000000000068ce4d <+125>:   sha256rnds2 %xmm0,0x2f0(%rsp),%xmm1
   0x000000000068ce56 <+134>:   pshufd $0xe,%xmm2,%xmm3
   0x000000000068ce5b <+139>:   movdqa %xmm13,%xmm2
   0x000000000068ce60 <+144>:   movaps %xmm1,0x2e0(%rsp)
   0x000000000068ce68 <+152>:   movq   %xmm3,%xmm0
   0x000000000068ce6c <+156>:   sha256rnds2 %xmm0,0x2e0(%rsp),%xmm2
   0x000000000068ce75 <+165>:   movdqu 0x10(%rsi),%xmm3
   0x000000000068ce7a <+170>:   pshufb %xmm8,%xmm3
   0x000000000068ce80 <+176>:   movaps %xmm2,0x2d0(%rsp)
   0x000000000068ce88 <+184>:   movdqa %xmm3,%xmm4
   0x000000000068ce8c <+188>:   paddd  0x6729c(%rip),%xmm4        # 0x6f4130
   0x000000000068ce94 <+196>:   movq   %xmm4,%xmm0
   0x000000000068ce98 <+200>:   sha256rnds2 %xmm0,0x2d0(%rsp),%xmm1
   ...
```

For example, `0068ce8c` though `0068ce98` should have been:

```
paddd  0x6729c(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x6f4130
sha256rnds2 %xmm0,0x2d0(%rsp),%xmm1
```

I'm guessing our choice of inline asm instructions are a bit off.

How do we work around the lack of `Yz` machine constraint under Clang? What pattern avoids the intermediate move in optimized code?

---

Attempting to use [Explicit Register Variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables):

```
const __m128i k asm("xmm0") = c;
asm ("sha256rnds2 %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(a) : "xm"(b), "x" (k));
return a;
```

Results in:

```
In file included from sha.cpp:24:
./cpu.h:831:22: warning: ignored asm label 'xmm0' on automatic variable
        const __m128i k asm("xmm0") = c;
                            ^
./cpu.h:833:7: error: invalid operand for instruction
        asm ("sha256rnds2 %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(a) : "xm"(b), "x" (k));
             ^
<inline asm>:1:21: note: instantiated into assembly here
        sha256rnds2 %xmm1, 752(%rsp), %xmm0
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from sha.cpp:24:
./cpu.h:833:7: error: invalid operand for instruction
        asm ("sha256rnds2 %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(a) : "xm"(b), "x" (k));
             ^
<inline asm>:1:21: note: instantiated into assembly here
        sha256rnds2 %xmm3, 736(%rsp), %xmm1
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
...
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. GCC calls that [Explicit Register Variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables). Clang will not compile it. I've tried a number of different ways using C++ and C casts. I think it has something to do with the `__m128i` type.

Comment: Looking at your update you are missing the `register` type qualifier on your temporary variable which is required to use an explicit register. Try `register const __m128i k asm("xmm0") = c;`

Comment: Thanks Michael. The `register` keyword is going away in C++, so we can't use it. (We are a C++ library, and this code is in a header file. Maybe I need to find a compiler specific workaround, like `__register` or `GCC_REGISTER`).

Comment: I know that `register` was "deprecated" in C++11, but you say "is going away". Has that been made part of the C++17 standard for sure? I haven't been keeping up, and Google turns up only a proposal, no definitive information. And even with that proposal, it remains "reserved", so using it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created this answer based on the tag `inline assembly` with no specific language mentioned. [Extended assembly templates](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) already assume use of extensions to the languages.

If the `Yz` constraint isn't available you can attempt to create a temporary variable to tell *CLANG* what register to use rather than a constraint. You can do this through what is called an [Explicit Register Variable](https://web.archive.org/web/20160821083608/https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables):

> You can define a local register variable and associate it with a specified register like this:
>
> ```
>  register int *foo asm ("r12");
> ```
>
> Here r12 is the name of the register that should be used. Note that this is the same syntax used for defining global register variables, but for a local variable the declaration appears within a function. The register keyword is required, and cannot be combined with static. The register name must be a valid register name for the target platform.

In your case you wish to force usage of `xmm0` register. You could assign the `c` parameter to a temporary variable using an explicit register and use that temporary as a parameter to the Extended Inline Assembly. This is the primary purpose of explicit registers in *GCC/CLANG*.

```
GCC_INLINE __m128i GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB
MM_SHA256RNDS2_EPU32(__m128i a, const __m128i b, const __m128i c)
{
   register const __m128i tmpc asm("xmm0") = c;
   __asm__("sha256rnds2 %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(a) : "x"(b), "x" (tmpc));
    return a;
}
```

The compiler should be able to provide some optimizations now since it has more knowledge as to how the `xmm0` register is to be used.

When you placed `mov %2, %%xmm0;` into the template *CLANG* (and *GCC*) do not do any optimizations on the instructions. Basic Assembly and Extended Assembly templates are a black box that it only knows how to do basic substitution based on the constraints.

---

Here's a disassembly using the method above. It was compiled with `clang++` and `-std=c++03`. The extra moves are no longer present:

```
Breakpoint 1, SHA256_SSE_SHA_HashBlocks (state=0x7fffffffae60,
    data=0x7fffffffae00, length=0x40) at sha.cpp:1101
1101        STATE1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) &state[4]);
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function SHA256_SSE_SHA_HashBlocks(unsigned int*, unsigned int const*, unsigned long):
   0x000000000068cf60 <+0>:     sub    $0x308,%rsp
   0x000000000068cf67 <+7>:     movdqu (%rdi),%xmm0
   0x000000000068cf6b <+11>:    movdqu 0x10(%rdi),%xmm1
...
   0x000000000068cfe6 <+134>:   paddd  0x670e2(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x6f40d0
   0x000000000068cfee <+142>:   sha256rnds2 %xmm0,0x2f0(%rsp),%xmm2
   0x000000000068cff7 <+151>:   pshufd $0xe,%xmm0,%xmm1
   0x000000000068cffc <+156>:   movdqa %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x000000000068d000 <+160>:   movaps %xmm2,0x2e0(%rsp)
   0x000000000068d008 <+168>:   sha256rnds2 %xmm0,0x2e0(%rsp),%xmm3
   0x000000000068d011 <+177>:   movdqu 0x10(%rsi),%xmm5
   0x000000000068d016 <+182>:   pshufb %xmm9,%xmm5
   0x000000000068d01c <+188>:   movaps %xmm3,0x2d0(%rsp)
   0x000000000068d024 <+196>:   movdqa %xmm5,%xmm0
   0x000000000068d028 <+200>:   paddd  0x670b0(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x6f40e0
   0x000000000068d030 <+208>:   sha256rnds2 %xmm0,0x2d0(%rsp),%xmm2
...
```

Comment: I would not worry about the C or C++ too much. Your answer may help someone working with Clang, SSE and inline assembly. Those are the important parts. You got my upvote.

Comment: I think the next question would be, how far can we bend the rules. Is using `register` in the context of explicit register variables simply engaging an extension such that the language is not violated. I'm probably going to ask the Clang and/or GCC devs.

Comment: @jww well if you go by c++17 it moves to reserved not just deprecated which provides a more significant problem. Better support for SIMD registers in inline assembly would be preferable as long as the intrinsics may lag behind compiler development. Either that or someone will come up with a language extension that doesn't violate the standard and allows explicit registers.

Comment: I meant _CPU development_ in my last comment, not _compiler development_. The odd man out for the `Yz` constraint seems to be CLANG. Versions of ICC (16+) supports it as well

Comment: Regarding *"how far can we bend the rules..."*, the [GCC 7 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html) state: *"`-Wregister` warns about uses of the register storage specifier. In C++17 this keyword has been removed and for C++17 this is a pedantic warning enabled by default. The warning is not emitted for the GNU Explicit Register Variables extension."*