# (v) is actually (*&v) since when?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Could C++ standards gurus please enlighten me:

Since which C++ standard version has this statement failed because `(v)` seems to be equivalent to `(*&v)`?

I.e. for example the code:

```
 #define DEC(V) ( ((V)>0)? ((V)-=1) : 0 )
 ...{...
        register int v=1;
        int r = DEC(v) ;
 ...}...
```

This now produces warnings under `-std=c++17` like:

> cannot take address of register variable
>
> left hand side of operand must be lvalue

Many C macros enclose ALL macro parameters in parentheses, of which the above is meant only to be a representative example.

The actual macros that produce warnings are for instance
the `RTA_*` macros in `/usr/include/linux/rtnetlink.h`.

Short of not using/redefining these macros in C++, is there any workaround?

Comment: @ildjarn sorry, but what significance does that have? Seems like answering my question by saying "questions has always had a question mark at their end".

Comment: Perhaps this warning is shown because `decltype<(x)>` is *always* a reference type?

Comment: C has this rule that "register" variables may not be the operand of the address-of operator, but C++ hadn't and with C++1z the keyword was removed, so perhaps the compiler follows C rules. But clearly there's no address-of operator in your code, so I recommend you remove all the dots and provide us with a complete minimal example that reproduces your error message.

Comment: I am without good internet and the standard at hand, but I remember some rules about the ternary operator that make the result operands references to {l,gr,x}values, and afaik gcc internally handles pointers and references pretty similar, leading to warnings of "taking address" when you form a reference too.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that warning, with `g++ -std=c++17 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++` and a [mcve] that looks like `#define DEC(V) ( ((V)>0)? ((V)-=1) : 0 )

int main()
{
    register int v=1;
    int r = DEC(v);
    return r;
}`.  That's with g++ version 6.3.0.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? This code compiles fine on GCC 7.1. as seen here: https://godbolt.org/g/Aebg1u

Comment: I have just now built gcc-7.1 - it is still running its test suite . I was building with gcc-5.4.0

Comment: I was also hoping to see if https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66944 is fixed

Comment: The actual macro that generates the warning, with '-Wall -Wextra -Werror', my default flsgs setting , is :

       #define RTA_ALIGNTO 4U
       #define RTA_ALIGN(len) ( ((len)+RTA_ALIGNTO-1) \
          & ~(RTA_ALIGNTO-1) )
       #define RTA_OK(rta,len) ((len) >= (int)sizeof(struct rtattr) && \
    (rta)->rta_len >= sizeof(struct rtattr) && \
    (rta)->rta_len <= (len))
       #define RTA_NEXT(rta,attrlen) ((attrlen) -=  RTA_ALIGN((rta)->rta_len), \
     (struct rtattr*)(((char*)(rta)) + RTA_ALIGN((rta)->rta_len)))

Comment: I'm like C++, but this `#define DEC(V) ( ((V)>0)? ((V)-=1) : 0 )` really looks scary.

Comment: What... does the question have to do with the title?

Answer (score 16):

If you look at the revision summary of the latest C++1z draft, you'd see this in [[diff.cpp14.dcl.dcl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp14.dcl.dcl#:register_storage_class)

> [dcl.stc]
>   **Change:** Removal of register storage-class-specifier.
>   **Rationale:** Enable repurposing of deprecated keyword in future
>   revisions of this International Standard.
>   **Effect on original feature:** A valid C++ 2014 declaration utilizing the register
>   storage-class-specifier is ill-formed in this International Standard.
>   The specifier can simply be removed to retain the original meaning.

The warning may be due to that.

Comment: AHA!  Thanks for pointing that out. But is that still true with '-std=gnu++17' ? 
investigating ...

Comment: Also see [Replacement for deprecated register keyword C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20618008/1708801)

Answer (score 13):

`register` is no longer a storage class specifier, you should remove it.  Compilers may not be issuing the right error or warnings but your code should not have `register` to begin with

The following is a quote from the standard informing people about what they should do with regards to `register` in their code (relevant part emphasized), you probably have an old version of that file

**C.1.6 Clause 10: declarations [diff.dcl]**

> Change: In C++, register is not a storage class specifier.
>
> Rationale: The storage class specifier had no effect in C++.
> Effect on original feature: Deletion of semantically well-defined feature.
>
> **Difficulty of converting**: Syntactic transformation.
>
> How widely used: Common.

Comment: Since `register` is no longer a storage class specifier, how do you tell the compiler that you want to store something in a register?

Comment: You don't, @Venemo. You haven't been able to tell the compiler that for a *very* long time. No big loss; the optimizer makes far better decisions than you could ever could about register allocation. The `register` storage-class specifier was simply ignored by the compiler, as far as the obvious meaning goes. All it meant is that the compiler would produce an error if you tried to take the address of a variable so declared.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're totally right, @T.C. It is only the C standard that makes it an error to take the address of a `register` variable. In C++ (prior to C++17, of course), `register` was simply ignored by the compiler when you took the address of such a variable.

Answer (score 6):

Your worry is unwarranted since the file in question does not actually contain the `register` keyword:

```
grep "register" /usr/include/linux/rtnetlink.h
```

outputs nothing. Either way, you shouldn't be receiving the warning since:

- System headers don't emit warnings by default, at least in GCC
- It isn't wise to try to compile a file that belongs to a systems project like the linux kernel in C++ mode, as there may be subtle and nasty breaking changes

Just include the file normally or link the C code to your C++ binary. Report a bug if you really are getting a warning that should normally be suppressed to your compiler vendor.

Comment: the "rtnetlink.h" file was never assumed to contain `register` in the question, but rather macros that clash with the use of that (deprecated) keyword.

Comment: OK, many thanks for all the responses, I can do :

            #if __GNUCXX__ > SOME_VALUE
            #  define register
            #endif

Comment: @JVD: No point in the `#if`. In fact, the opposite might become relevant. Like `auto`, `register` might be repurposed for more useful language features.