# What is the correct way to tell the compiler that I want a variable to be always stored in a register?

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, inline-assembly, cortex-m

Reading the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693175/v-is-actually-v-since-when) it came to my attention that `register` is no longer a valid storage specifier in C++17. Some comments even suggest that the compiler had already ignored `register` for some time.

I use GCC 6.x with an ARM Cortex-M MCU and have some piece of code with inline assembly which absolutely need to have a variable in a register. Previously I had assumed that the `register` keyword will do this for me, but apparently it doesn't.

- In modern C++, what is the correct way to ensure that the compiler always uses a register for a given variable?
- If there isn't a standard way, is there a GCC-specific way of doing this? Maybe some sort of attribute? Or a compiler specific keyword?

**EDIT**: Why do I need to store something in a register?
I'm implemeting a lock-free ring buffer with the ARM `LDREX` / `STREX` instructions. I need to store the result of the ARM `LDREX` instruction in a register, because storing it in memory would defeat the whole mechanism on a Cortex-M.

**EDIT**: Example code.

This is a code snippet cut from the ring buffer to illustrate the point of the question. The points of interest are `__LDREXW`, `__STREXW` and `__CLREX` which are all defined in `cmsis_gcc.h`. [They are intrinsic functions of the ARM synchronization primitives.](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABDEEJC.html) I use them to implement a lock-free mechanism.

```
template<typename T, uint32_t maxCount>
class RingBuffer final {

    __attribute__((aligned(8)))
    T buffer[maxCount];
    uint32_t start;
    uint32_t end;

    bool pushBack(const T &item) {
        register uint32_t exclusiveEnd;
        register uint32_t oldEnd;

        do {
            // Load current end value exclusively
            exclusiveEnd = __LDREXW(&end);
            __DMB();

            // Remember old end value so that
            // we can store the item at that location
            oldEnd = exclusiveEnd;

            // Check if ring buffer is full
            if (isFull()) {
                __CLREX();
                __DMB();
                return false;
            }

            // Figure out correct new value
            if (exclusiveEnd == (maxCount - 1)) {
                exclusiveEnd = 0;
            }
            else {
                exclusiveEnd ++;
            }

            // Attempt to store new end value
        } while (0 != __STREXW(exclusiveEnd, &end));
        __CLREX();
        __DMB();

        // Store new item
        //memcpy(buffer + oldEnd, &item, sizeof(T));
        buffer[oldEnd] = item;
        return true;
    }

    // ... other methods ...

}
```

Why the `LDREX` result must be stored in a register:

On the Cortex-M4 *the implemented exclusives reservation granule is the entire memory address range* (quoted from Cortex-M4 TRM), which means if the variable storing the `LDREX` result ends up in memory instead of a register, then the following `STREX` will always fail.

NOTE: this code runs on "bare-metal" hardware, there is no operating system, etc.

Comment: There is no way to do this in C++ short of writing everything in inline assembly.

Comment: @nwp - inline assembly might not do it either; the compiler can rearrange your code. The only way to truly know is to write a separate ASM file.

Comment: Why does it absolutely need to be in a register?  Performance? Or is there some other reason?  If it's just performance, then you could try writing in plain C++ and seeing if the optimizer gets it right.

Comment: Don't create a variable.  Refactor your code to use the expression where you assign to the variable at the place you need the value.

Comment: @MartinBonner Added an explanation as to why I need a register.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html#Explicit-Register-Variables

Comment: Using `ldrex`/`strex` in separate `asm` statements has always been an invalid use of inline assembly.

Comment: While there is [-ffixed-reg](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-ffixed) and the "Global Register Variables" rici mentions, you have to remember they only affect the compiler, not the linker.  So if you link to a library (like the C runtime) that has NOT been compiled with this switch, the library will use the register as the ABI defines. Also, given that registers are a limited and valuable resource, are you SURE reserving one like this is the best answer?  Having fewer registers available can end up negatively impacting the performance of ALL the rest of your code.

Comment: @stark there's no guarantee that your method doesn't spill the register to the stack.

Comment: remind us again what you think ldrex and strex really do and how they help you here and what that would have to do with a register.  Your real problem is you want to do a lock free ring buffer on a uniprocessor core, and you think ldrex/strex has something to do with that, I think you need to back all the way back to the actual goal and then move forward, how do I make a lock free ring buffer on a cortex-m here is what I tried and this is what I think it should have done and I dont think it is working.

Comment: @old_timer Excellent points.  Additionally, what does `ldrex/strex` do when the reserve granule is all system memory.  How is it different than a normal mutex or even locking interrupts.  As well, it is long known that a single read/writer of a ring buffer is already lock free as long a the `start` and `end` are globally visible to all software entities.  See: Knuth's **Art of computer..** or Linux [kfifo](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kfifo.h) for instance.  `ldrex/strex` are used for more complex data structures; with multiple CPUs and smaller granule.

Comment: ldrex/strex are/were put there to allow the various cores in a multicore processor to access things, they are/were not direct replacements for swp although they have come to be used for that.  Wanting to remember that they arent actually implemented as one would expect in a cortex-m, thought we covered that in a question here, but would have to re-visit that to confirm, or maybe it is optional when you build the core.

Comment: point being the OP is a handful of steps along a line of assumptions and if any or all fail then the whole path falls apart, and I think that has happened.

Comment: Why not use std::atomic instead of trying to implement it yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the correct way to tell the compiler that I want a variable to be always stored in a register?

You can't do that (in portable standard C++ or C code). You need to **trust your compiler**, so you should not even want to do that.

Notice that:

- Recent C & C++ standards (e.g. C11 or C++14 or C++17) don't speak of *processor registers* in an imperative way, and they mention that the `register` keyword **was** (in the previous century) only **a hint** for compilers.
- Some processors don't (at least in the past) even have any real programmer accessible processor register.
- Most importantly, you should **trust your compiler for good enough [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)** and in some cases putting a value in a register is *not* the best for performance (in particular, because that register could be better used for some other value).

However, as an **extension** the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler enables you to put a [variable in a specified register](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html). **I don't recommend using that** without *very good* reasons (at least be sure to benchmark your code with and without using that feature).

You really need to understand that **current compilers are** most of the time **optimizing better than you can do**. Be sure to benchmark your code (e.g. compiled with `g++ -O3` and appropriate `-mtune=` argument) before trying to optimize by hand. For performance sensitive routines, examine also the generated assembler code (e.g. with `g++ -O3 -fverbose-asm -S`).

> On the Cortex-M4 the implemented exclusives reservation granule is the entire memory address range (quoted from Cortex-M4 TRM),

Then I recommend either using a *small* [extended assembler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) code (for GCC) or, *if absolutely necessary*, declare a  [variable in a specified register](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html)

Perhaps you also need to compile *all your code* (including any used library, including standard C and C++ libraries!) with [`-ffixed-`*reg*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) option.

But I insist: you need to trust your compiler more than you currently do. Are you sure you can't find (and perhaps configure and build from source) a *recent* GCC (e.g. GCC 7) which enables, as a builtin or something else, your low-level synchronization mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

`register` has mostly been treated as a hint by C++ compilers, even before the first standard, which was ratified in 1998.   And, in a lot of cases, the compiler has been able to do a significantly better job of register allocation than programmers, so it has ignored that hint.

There is no general or portable way in standard C++ (i.e. one that works with compilers from different vendors, and on different host systems) to ensure a particular variable is placed in a register.

It is possible, with some compilers, to use inline assembler to explicitly use registers.   The catch with this approach is that inline assembler varies between compilers and hosts (essentially, it is implementation defined).   Several modern compilers are also aggressive enough that they optimise inline assembler as well, so may remove usage of a register even in inline assembler.   The analysis and transformations are often relatively simple (in comparison with other types of optimisations, at least), so may happen even with low optimisation settings.

The only way to know for sure is to examine the output assembler to determine what the compiler does, for your chosen settings (optimisation, etc).

Probably the only sure-fire way is to write your code in assembler, rather than as inline assembler in C++.   (I'm not aware of any assembler that optimises code to a great extent, but I've never had reason to try and find one either).  By definition, that is not portable between systems - assembler is often machine dependent.

Your choice of words

> Previously I had assumed that the `register` keyword will do this for me, but apparently it doesn't.

also raises another potential concern - that you are attempting to force use of registers unnecessarily.

If you previously assumed the `register` keyword was sufficient, and your program appears to have worked as required anyway, it's quite possible that there is no need for you to worry if any variable is in a register.

My point is, if performance is critical enough to justify forcing any variable into a register, you should have *known* that your compiler was placing your chosen variable in a register, not just assumed that to be so.   If you have just assumed that is true, and not encountered difficulties, it's quite possible the compiler was ignoring the hint, and achieving your required performance for your code anyway.

I suggest you need to question and revalidate your belief that your particular variable actually needs to be stored in a register.

Without information about your design requirements - and evidence through substantial testing that compiled code does not meet those requirements in realistic scenarios - the assumption that you need to use a register is often misplaced.

Comment: See the edit in my question as to why I need to use a register.

Comment: And yes, in this case it is perfectly okay for me to use compiler-specific stuff.

Comment: I'm actually curious, does compiler optimize assembly even if its declared `volatile`? Last I checked, `asm volatile` is the goto way of killing the optimizer